# How to make a Firefox Extension URL Button show a string when hovered over

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have made my full FF extension, and there is a button in the URL bar. The boss now wants the button to show a certain string when you hover over it. Here is my current code for the button:

```
var loadURLButton = function(doc, urlBtnClick) {
    var urlBarIcons = doc.getElementById('urlbar-icons')
    var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'urlbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('image', require('sdk/self').data.url("canNone.png"));
    btn.addEventListener('command', urlBtnClick, false);
    urlBarIcons.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
}

var doc = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document;

var urlbarButton = loadURLButton(doc, openTab);
```

What can I add to this in order to make some id pop up on hover?

Comment: Try: `btn.setAttribute('tooltip', 'blah')`

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. I also tried label, but I think that's for something else.

Comment: @JasePellerin Remember [the extension I told you about](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/)? Just use it to inspect a button that already does what you want, like the refresh URL button, and imitate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awwwww man all that work for nothing. The attribute is not tooltip but it is tooltiptext! So just do btn.setAttribute('tooltiptext', 'what ever you want');

```
var loadURLButton = function(doc, urlBtnClick) {
    var urlBarIcons = doc.getElementById('urlbar-icons')
    var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'urlbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('tooltiptext', 'mytt');
    btn.setAttribute('image', 'chrome://branding/content/icon32.png');
    btn.addEventListener('command', urlBtnClick, false);
    urlBarIcons.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
}

var doc = document;

var urlbarButton = loadURLButton(doc, null);
```

Comment: This is perfect and so easy! You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue i tried setting attribute of tooltip on it and all the anonys children and it didnt work.

So Im thinking of attachinga panel to it. This code doesnt work but we're in the right direction:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/panel#Examples

```
var loadURLButton = function(doc, urlBtnClick) {
    var urlBarIcons = doc.getElementById('urlbar-icons')
    var tooltip = doc.createElement('panel');
    tooltip.setAttribute('style', 'width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;');
    tooltip.setAttribute('id', 'mytt');
    tooltip.textContent = 'my toold tip';
    var btn = doc.createElement('toolbarbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'urlbutton');
    btn.setAttribute('tooltip', 'mytt');
    btn.setAttribute('image', 'chrome://branding/content/icon32.png');
    btn.addEventListener('command', urlBtnClick, false);
    btn.appendChild(tooltip)
    urlBarIcons.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
}

var doc = document;

var urlbarButton = loadURLButton(doc, null);
```

Comment: That definitely seems to get us closer. Should we maybe add an eventListener for mouseenter that calls that popup?

Comment: Refresh the page i edited, so now when u click it shows the panel. Im thinking addEventListener for mouseenter and show tooltip after some time. Because it looks like the xul `popup` attribute is only triggered by click:

Comment: EDIT!! Wait I got it! Instead of popup use tooltip attribute see edit!

Comment: Edited again to give it `textContent`, cheating way, if you dont want to append a label and set its value. Works nicely :)