# How to create a tool tip with some content on top of the selected text

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to create a fire fox plugin to display the word's meaning when selected. How to create a tool tip with some content on top  of the selected text ?

Comment: that can be achieved with standard web technologies, it's not really firefox-specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27322087/1828637