# Title Attribute not working in Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox-addon, title, mozilla

I am developing a mozilla firefox addon. I need a hover tooltip for a icon in my panel of firefox extension. When i use the title attribute the tooltip is not displaying. Suggest me a solution .

P.S : I am specifiying about the firefox addon or extension , not the browser

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check this topic out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320871/how-to-make-a-firefox-extension-url-button-show-a-string-when-hovered-over/27322368#27322368

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Did @lucky's solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you just need to do this:

```
myElement = document.createElement("someXULtagName");
myElement.setAttribute("tooltiptext","My tooltip text");
```

But inside panels (at least non-SDK ones) you have to do more work if you are including HTML elements instead of XUL elements:

```
myPanelview = document.createElement('panelview');
myPanelview.setAttribute('tooltip', 'aHTMLTooltip');
...
myElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', "someHTMLtagName");
myElement.setAttribute("title","My tooltip text");
```

Comment: Hi, I display the title same as the above method by `myPanelview.setAttribute('tooltip', 'aHTMLTooltip');` and it displays what is present in  the title tag of my HTML file. But I want to modify the tooltip or cuztomize the height and width of the tooltip box. How coud i do that? Please give me a solution ,