# Firefox's add-on SDK: no tooltip for context-menu?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) about `context-menu` not mentioned `tooltip`. Is it not possible to show pop-up text when user hover on my item menu?

Comment: I dont know of the sdk methods (but im no sdk expert) but this is how you do it non sdk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320871/how-to-make-a-firefox-extension-url-button-show-a-string-when-hovered-over/27322368#27322368

Comment: @Noitidart `menuItem.setAttribute('tooltip', 'test')`: TypeError: is not a function

Comment: Jump on irc people there will help you out https://client02.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23extdev

Comment: @Noitidart thanks, I will try

Comment: Can you get on irc this weekend I can help you out

Comment: @Noitidart maybe you will answer here for future searchers?

Comment: I really would love to but im not an sdk guy so i need you to write it for me and reproduce for me on my computer or your computer and show me, and then i can plug in the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, with some extra code.

First you need a dummy menu item that will serve as a trigger and subsequently will add the tooltips to the actual menu items.

It is easy to find out which menu items are constructed by the addon-sdk module because they have the class `addon-context-menu-item`. The difficult part it to identify those that belong to your extension.

One way to achieve this it to utilize the `data` attribute of `Item` class constructor, which conveniently maps to the `value` attribute of the underlying xul element.

So if `data` consists of unique prefix and the desired tooltip text, it is just a matter of kicking in the right moment.

```js
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require("sdk/window/utils");

var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var uuid = require('sdk/util/uuid').uuid();
var uuidstr = uuid.number.substring(1,37)

cm.Item({
  label: "My Menu Item",
  context: cm.URLContext("*.mozilla.org"),
  data: uuidstr+"This is a cool tooltip"
});

cm.Item({
  label: "global Item",
  data: uuidstr+"Tooltips FTW"
});

cm.Item({
  label: "Just a tigger, will never show up",
  contentScript: 'self.on("context", function(){self.postMessage(); return false;})',
  onMessage: function(){
    var chromewin = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    var cmitems = chromewin.document.querySelectorAll(".addon-context-menu-item[value^='"+ uuidstr +"']");
    for(var i=0; i < cmitems.length; i++)
      cmitems[i].tooltipText = cmitems[i].value.substring(36);
  }
})
```

if you already use `data` you have to do some extra work.

Comment: I get this error: `chromewin.document is undefined`. You can see my code here https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/lib/main.js

Comment: correct [line 57](https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich/extension-firefox-yandex-translate/blob/master/lib/main.js#L52), getMostRecentBrowserWindow is a function.