# Add Custom Tooltip style to Panel of Mozilla add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, add-on

I am developing a Mozilla add-on , in which I display the tooltip for the content in panel by setting the `tooltiptext` attribute for the panelview of addon-SDK. I need to apply a `style` for the `tooltiptext` of the panel , So please suggest me a solution to add `style` for the existing tooltip or add a custom tooltip.

P.S : I am talking about the Mozilla add-on , not the Mozilla browser.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myPanel = Panel({
   width: 180,
   height: 180,
   contentURL: 'data:text/html,<textarea style="width:120px; height:80px;">this is my textarea</textarea>'
})

let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
let myPanelView = getActiveView(myPanel);
myPanelView.setAttribute("noautohide", true);
myPanelView.setAttribute("level", 'top');
myPanelView.setAttribute("style", 'background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);');
```

You can add whatever you want with this method.

Comment: But how could I add change the stye of the tooltiptext of my panel?@Noitidart

Comment: You haven't shown any code. But there are many ways to do tooltips. If you did this method:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27322087/1828637 then you just style the panel that you assigned in the `tooltip` attribute in the same way as above.